# selection sort running time confusion

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

According to
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/21elementary/
"Selection sort uses ~N<sup>2</sup>/2 compares and N exchanges to sort an array of length N."
For example I have two items in the array.
    String[] a = {"h","t"};
Can I asume that selection sort uses 2<sup>2</sup>/2 = 2 compares and 2 exchanges to sort an array of length 2?
But when I run this:
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/21elementary/Selection.java.html
It only compared once. Of course it's common sence because the only items to compare are h and t. But I'm still confused by the statement. Is their something wrong with my experiment? I'm new at this.

Comment: ~N^2/2 means approximately. I don't have a copy of the book, but I imagine Sedgewick defines exactly what ~ means in the introduction.

Comment: It says `~N^2/2`, right? Doesn't `~` mean 'roughly'?

Comment: May bad. I don't know what ~ means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selection sort uses approximately N^2/2 comparisons and N exchanges.

For an exact analysis, selection sort uses

N-1 + N-2 + N-3 + .....1 comparisons to sort an array of length N.

Thus total number of comparisons = (N-1)*(N)/2 = N^2/2 - N/2  which is approximately equal to N^2/2 . Which is what they have written.

In your example when N is 2, comparisons = 1*2/2  = 1.
And the number of exchanges is = 1. (N-1)

Answer (score 0):

The notation f(n) ~ g(n) means:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1
$$

In this particular case, you see that the first element is compared to other $n - 1$, the second to $n - 2$, until the next-to-last with 1. So the number of comparisons is:

(n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 1 = n (n - 1) / 2 ~ n^2 / 2

Comment: PS: *Please* support MathJax for this site. Us CSc types feel seriously cramped.

Comment: I doubt that's going to happen - there's a Meta post about this here somewhere - something about being resource heavy and not necessary here. But you really shouldn't post posts assuming that it works, because, as it stands, it doesn't look very pretty. There are online tools to generate images for that which you can paste here instead, if you wish.